# How to use this in sql -- > max(sum (paid * quantity )) to solve a query

Tags: sql

How to get the max value order of each customer ?

```
select  num,  max(sum(paid*quantity))
from orders join
     pizza
     using (order#)
group by customer#;
```

table

```
num     orderN    price
-------- ---   -------
     1   109       30
     1   118       25
     3   101       30
     3   115       27
     4   107       23
     5   100       17
     5   129       16
```

output req-

```
num     Pnum    price
-------- ---   -------
     1   109       30
     3   101       30
     4   107       23
     5   100       17
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: Did that please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the record having the highest `price` in each group of `num`s.

If your RDBMS supports window functions, that's straight forward with `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT num, pnum, price
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY num ORDER BY price DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Else, you can take the following approach, that uses a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery to ensure that the record being joined in the one with the highest price for the current `num` :

```
SELECT num, pnum, price
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable t1 WHERE t1.num = t.num AND t1.price > t.price
)
```

Comment: the price is sum(quantity * paid)

Comment: @TheSINGHVlogs... Sure, but you did not show column `paid` in your sample data...

Comment: the price is alias for paid

Comment: @TheSINGHVlogs : ok, then what about column `quantity` ? is it `pnum` ?